# How to get a message when the map is moved in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to get a message when every time I move the map.

I had:

```
def info(self):
    QMessageBox.information( self, self.tr( "Info" ), self.tr("info") )
```

I suppose that used to be something like that...

```
iface.mapCanvas().???.connect(self.info)
```

Comment: By moved you mean moving the viewport, the position in the legend or the actual file/database where the layer/map is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **extentsChanged()** signal. This is emitted every time, the map canvas is moved or zoomed.

The following code works from the python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

def info():
    QMessageBox.information( iface.mapCanvas(), "Extents changed", "Pan or zoom occurred" )

iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.connect(info)
```

Adjusting it to be used from a a python object (like in a plugin) should be easy, the necessary *self*-parameters are in the question code already.

There is no information about the new extents emitted with the signal, but this can be easily queried with

```
iface.mapCanvas().extent()
```

Comment: @underdark This should also work for QGIS 2.x, doesn't it?

Comment: The signal/slot mechanism has changed, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72696/how-to-programmatically-detect-a-canvas-refresh-or-pan-zoom-in-qgis?lq=1

Comment: They are different use-cases available in both versions. The signal mentioned in this answer only gets emitted when the extent changes (pan / zoom) the other one gets emitted whenever the map canvas is repainted (e.g. symbology change).

Comment: sorry, my fault