# How to programmatically detect a canvas refresh or pan/zoom in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

For my python plugin I would like to remove a VertexMarker when the user pans/zooms there map.

Which is the best way to detect a canvas refresh or pan/zoom carried out by the user?

Can you suggest any plugins which have this functionality I can take a look at?

Thanks

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58700/how-to-get-a-message-when-the-map-is-moved-in-qgis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just connect to the refresh signal

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.connect(yourmethod)
```